# How to I get javascript date split code to work for all browsers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have a piece of code that works in Chrome and MSIE but failing in Opera and Firefox

```
var end = Browser.getValue(getElement("mydate"));
var parts = end.split('.');
var us_date = parts[1]+'/'+parts[0]+'/'+parts[2];


var someDate = new Date(us_date);
var numberOfDaysRemove = 1;
someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() - numberOfDaysRemove);

var returndate = someDate.getDate() + '.' + (someDate.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + someDate.getFullYear() + " " + someDate.getHours() + ':' + someDate.getMinutes();
```

I know why it doesn't work in Opera and Firefox as I need to replace the

```
var parts = end.split('.');
var returndate = someDate.getDate() + '.' + (someDate.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + someDate.getFullYear() + " " + someDate.getHours() + ':' + someDate.getMinutes();
```

with

```
var parts = end.split('/');
var returndate = someDate.getDate() + '/' + (someDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + someDate.getFullYear() + " " + someDate.getHours() + ':' + someDate.getMinutes();
```

When I do this then it won't work in Chrome or MSIE.

Is there a way to get this code to work in all browsers?

Comment: did you try to use moment.js?

Comment: Never hear of moment.js. I am new to JS

Comment: I cant figure out why you use Browser.getValue(getElement("mydate")); Tell me more about your use case please..

Comment: Sorry.. there is an element id in there.. I just rename it to mydate.. It is in EU format (dd.MM.YYYY) so I need to split and reset to US date format so I can use the JS date functions.

Comment: "*How to I get javascript code to work for all browsers*" - every developer ever

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫—in this case, that requirement is trivial, the OP is 90% of the way there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **never** parse strings using the Date constructor or Date.parse (which do the same thing) as it is almost entirely implementation dependent and unreliable. **Always** manually parse strings, a library can help but if you only need to support one or two formats, a bespoke function is trivial.

Given that you have:

```
var end = Browser.getValue(getElement("mydate"));
var parts = end.split('.');
var us_date = parts[1]+'/'+parts[0]+'/'+parts[2];
```

I suspect *end* is something like "dd.mm.yyyy", so replace the last line with:

```
var someDate = new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]);
```

which will work in every browser since javascript was invented.

#### Edit

Presuming that the date string is "dd.mm.yyyy", a simple function to parse it regardless of the separator is:

```js
/* Parse date string in format d/m/y
** @param {string} s - date string
** @returns {Date} date object
*/
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[2], b[1]-1, b[0]);
}

document.write(parseDMY('23.01.2016'));
```

This assumes that the values are a valid date and will allow any non–digit separator, so d.m.y, d/m/y and d-m-y are all acceptable.

Comment: How do I get around the split? It shows in Chrome as "dd.mm.yyyy" but shows in Firefox as "dd/mm/yyyy" so splitting with "." doesn't work or do I just get the value and then use the line you added without split?

Comment: Tried the suggestion and it is return an invalid date message.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use something like jquery to manipulate the DOM.
Jquery, adding a level of abstraction, allows to avoid having to adapt the code to the "single browser standard", because even though today is a  bit better (than years ago), basically there is still no real standard.

So for instance, if you do $('#mydate') jquery will retrieve that element in every browser (using IE getElementById etc...) and you don't need anymore to worry about your code to be cross-browser.

$('#mydate').val() //assuming it to be an input, will retrieve the value and then you can work with your own logic.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have no clue about Jquery. was looking for a pure JS solution